# stream audio and video data separately

Tags: c#, opencv, audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm developing a C# video streaming application. 
At the moment I was able to capture video frames using opencv and encode it using ffmpeg and also capture and encode
audio using ffmpeg and save data in to queue.

The problem that I am facing is that when I send both streams simultaneously I am losing video stream.That means I stream it by first sending a video packet and then an audio packet. But, the player identifies video stream first and start to play. And did not play audio packets.

Can any one give a method to do this task?
It will be greatly appreciated.